Identify movie interrupted by Lockerbie news flash
21st December 1988 sometime between 7 and 8 pm I was watching a film on UK television when it was interrupted by a news flash announcing the Lockerbie Pan Am disaster.
The film was about two girls, probably early teens, who end up committing a murder.  The murder weapon was a gun.  The film was in an urban setting, with, I think, the killing taking place in a hotel room.  I think the girl who pulled the trigger had dark brown or black hair in a bob.  I don't remember anything else about the film since I was quite young.  It may have been a made-for-tv-movie and was in english - probably set in USA, maybe Australia, definitely not the UK.  It might have been based on a true story.  It definitely wasn't Heavenly Creatures (1994).
I have searched for what TV was interrupted by the Lockerbie disaster and another website said that Des O'Connor was on ITV and Les Dawson was on BBC1 so this film was either on BBC2 or Channel 4.

I'm now certain it was Poison Candy, a feature length drama screenplay by Anthony Simmons, based on the novel The Naughty Girls by Arthur Wise.  Can't find much detail on the programme but the novel is about two 9 year old girls who get involved in blackmail.  It may also go under the name of Little Sweetheart the brief synopsis of which is:  Crime, Florida.  Nine-year-old girl blackmails embezzler and frames him for killing little girl. BBC TV film made for cinemas.  Poison Candy was shown at 9pm on BBC 1.
I'm not sure of the relationship between Poison Candy and Little Sweetheart - the cast, director and writer are the same but on IMDB Little Sweetheart is listed as 1989 - the year after Poison Candy was shown on TV.

How firm are you on that exact date and time?
According to this website, between 7 and 8 pm on BBC Two they were airing some sort of "current affairs magazine programme" called Reportage.  Doesn't really sound like what you're describing, but it did apparently include a "phone poll for you to decide on subjects that matter" (eat it, American Idol!)  After that it was ten minutes of Tom & Jerry followed by a documentary on Liza Minnelli's father, Vincente, who was a famous Hollywood producer.  This ran until 9pm.  It mentions "...many glorious clips from his films..." so it's possible you saw one of those clips, although this is probably pushing outside your timeframe since this documentary started at 7:50pm
According to the December 1988 edition of TV Guide (captured in all its glory here) Channel 4 was airing the news between 7 and 8pm, followed at 8 by an episode of Brookside, which I gather was a fairly popular soap opera that ran from the early eighties until the early noughties.  The episode scheduled to air that day was called "Sacked", although the episode description I was able to find online was not very enlightening:

When Terry visits a wine bar, he's shocked by what he discovers. Paul finds the Christmas present Annabelle got from Brian. Ralph gets some bad news and Barry and Sinbad need to act quickly.

So, there are three possibilities I see:

It was a clip of some Vincente Minnelli movie, part of the documentary on BBC Two.  (I'll let you Google those if you think this is a possibility.)
It was a re-enactment scene as part of a news story on Channel 4 News (unlikely if you're really sure it wasn't set in the UK)
OR
It was that episode of Brookside, although I regrettably cannot find details about it that line up with what you describe.


The date is definite - the time not so much.  Thanks for the link to the Radiotimes archive, a very useful database - I have found the answer.  The programme was actually on BBC 1 from 9pm; a feature length drama - this is odd since I distinctly remember it being interrupted by the news - there must have been a second newsflash updating on the situation.
